# PhpStorm extremely slow while editing vue.js files

Tags: performance, vue.js, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 2017.1.4 with the vue.js plugin. The problem I have is: this plugin is **extremely** slow and makes coding impossible as you type and you don't see what you type only with 1 to 2 seconds lag. It takes 95% of allocated memory. It takes 50% of the CPU usage.

The project I'm working on is new and I have only one file open of less than 70 lines.

Settings offers to install for vue.js plugin v171.4424.63
I tried to install an earlier version of the plugin v171.3780.63 from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9442-vue-js but the result is the same.

Installing more recent versions wasn't supported by PhpStorm and showed it in red with the message "plugin is not compatible with current PhpStorm installation".

I already opened an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36715. But what do I do until they fix the issue? code on notepad?

Is there anything I can do to speed things up?

Comment: Similar issue exists with PhpStorm 2018.1 with Vue.js plugin 181.5087.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found what was making my specific project so slow and not other ones: I am using Laravel mix tool for versioning my js and sass files. I had more than 200 generated copies of each stored in the public directory. **Edit** <s>Even if I have added public\js and public\css to the .gitignore, phpStorm VCS (version control)</s> PhpStorm was taking almost all ressource to index these files. Now I deleted the unused files, the plugin is fast as it should be.

The question that remains now is why laravel mix is not deleting the previous versions of built css and js files?

Comment: 1) Why do you think it was VCS subsystem? 2) VCS does not index anything. Having file in `.gitignore` or alike does not mean that file should be ignored from usual "have this file changed outside" or "what this file has inside" checks. Indexing is general IDE feature -- used for code completion etc.

Comment: you are right, it is certainly not due to VSC, but to the indexing. Deleting manually these 200 files solved the issue. but now I have another issue: mix should delete old version files each time a new built is created. I opened another issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44353166/laravel-mix-versioning-doesnt-remove-old-built-files

Answer (score 17):

**Did this and solved my problem**

Tell `php` storm to ignore the `/public` dir for indexing.

1. Right-click a `dir` (like `public`, or `public/js`),
2. Choose `mark directory as` and select `excluded`.
3. `PHPStorm` will no longer index it when changes are made.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue and for me the problem was with **multiple copies of generated javascript files** by Encore / Webpack in public folder. Therefore, PhpStorm indexed all duplicates and was using all the duplicates for code completion / code navigation.

Excluding the folder with generated javascript files ([mark directory as **excluded** in PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html#project_tool_window)) helped!

(well, I should have excluded such folder long time ago)...

Comment: This fixed it for me! Problem was PHPStorm was indexing the new app.js everytime it was compiled

Answer (score -7):

I have never used the php storm plugin but maybe if you don't need the full IDE support you should consider using an editor like Sublime text or Visual studio code or Atom. They are lightning fast compared to an IDE.

Comment: In this case, I can remove the vue plugin and treat .vue files as html files. I would keep PhpStorm which is great for the rest of the code.