# Editing CSS in PhpStorm is so slow

Tags: css, phpstorm, webstorm, code-completion

Lately I've been editing CSS files in PhpStorm a lot lately, and I've noticed that the CSS code completion is very slow. Suggested display time is about 2-5 seconds.

I think PhpStorm scanned too many files before giving me a suggestion.

How to make PhpStorm stop scanning other CSS files before showing me suggestions?

[image]

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53715902/14945696)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion
It works well. But when I want to find something, it's a hindrance